# How can I count the number of comma separated numbers in a google spreadsheet?

Tags: count, google-sheets

I've got a cell which has values
1,2,3,4

I need a formula that returns 4 in another cell, however this Google spreadsheet looks really complicated. Also I need to trim because I might have white spaces between the numbers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One option is to use the following formula:

```
=COUNT(SPLIT(A1; ","))
```

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: @vivek_bye: The question was specifically on numerical values, so the answer was addressed in this regard. Another option, besides the one mentioned in the answer, is, in fact, use the COUNTA function. For details of each function see documentation. [COUNT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620) and [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991).

Answer (score 29):

Just so it is not missed when counting non-numeric items (thanks @noway and @wchiquito as count did not work for my text)

`=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,","))`

Comment: Thanks a bunch @brianlmerritt! Can you start the formula with "=" please? We are too lazy :P

Answer (score 19):

I came a bit late to the party, but:
if you want to count 0 when there is nothing in the cell...

`=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, ",")) - NOT(LEN(A1))`

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula :

```
=LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",",""))+1
```