# Grouping Preferences by email in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can you help me with below using Google Sheets to transform the Google Form data below to have a list of activities with a list of potential attendees?

**Context:**

- I am arranging a set of activities for a conference tour and wanted to try arrange everything using Google Forms.
- I have collected the data from the group attendees using the following format.
- Attendees can vote for any number of activities from a selection of 15
- The output format is: Email address - Comma Seperated field containing the target activities. (see below)

[image: Table of Data]

How do I switch the table to sort the data by indvidual activity, so I have the following format sorted by activity:
[image: Data sorted by Activity]

Comment: Related question: [Group everything by Column A and have Column B be a comma-delimited list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73698991/1330560)

Comment: Related question: [How to split and transpose results over 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17538337/1330560)

Comment: Related question: [How can I count the number of comma separated numbers in a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20493647/1330560)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected results are constructed in several stages:

**Final Outcome**

[image: stage 4]

---

**1. Split and transpose results over 2 columns**

`=query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")`

Refer: [How to transpose & split multiple columns and repeat specific cells in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67027283/1330560)

**2. Group everything by Email; Activities as a comma-delimited list**

`=query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col1")`

Refer: [Group everything by Column A and have Column B be a comma-delimited list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73715135/1330560)

**3. Count number of email addresses for each Activity**

`={"Number of Attendees";arrayformula(if(N2:N<>"",iferror(len(regexreplace(N2:N,"[^@^]","")),),))}`

Refer: [Count occurrences of string in a single cell in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67748524/1330560)

**4. Create "helper" queries as substitutes in Filter formula**

- **Email**

`=query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col1")`
``

- **Activities**

`=query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col2")`

**5. Combine everything into a single formula**

`={UNIQUE(FILTER(query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col2"), query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col1")<>"")),{"Number of Attendees";arrayformula(len(regexreplace(BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2")},"select Col2"), query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2")},"select Col1")<>"")), LAMBDA(aa, JOIN(", ", FILTER(query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2")},"select Col1"), query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2")},"select Col2")=aa)))),"[^@^]","")))}, BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col2"), query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col1")<>"")), LAMBDA(aa, JOIN(", ", FILTER(query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"),  "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col1"), query({query({ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))="",, if(A2:A5="","none",A2:A5)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B5, ", ",false))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null")))},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Email', Col2 'Activity'")},"select Col2")=aa))))}`

---

**Raw Data**

[image: raw data]

---

**Stage 1 - split and transpose results over 2 columns**

[image: stage1]

---

**Stage 2 - group by Activity; comma-delimited email addresses**

[image: stage 2]

---

**Stage 3 - Count email addresses in each Activities row**

[image: stage 3]

---

**Stage 4 - Helper queries**

[image: helper queries]

---